# $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n = 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is it really true that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n  = 1$$

?

We were taught throughout our entire math courses that $[1^{\infty}]$ is an undetermined form....Am I missing something here?

Comment: yes, $\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$.

Comment: Actually, $\lim_{x\to\infty}1^n=1^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it really true that 
>   $$\lim_{\color{red}{x}\to\infty} 1^n  = 1$$

You probably mean:
$$\lim_{\color{blue}{n}\to\infty} 1^n  = 1$$
and yes, this is true because $1^n = 1$ for all $n$.

The expression $"1^{+\infty}"$ *is* indeterminate and the limit above doesn't contradict that.

Perhaps you know the following well-known limit too:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\color{blue}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^\color{red}{n} = e \ne1$$where you also have $\color{blue}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$ and $\color{red}{n}\to+\infty$.

Combining both limits shows that you can have sequences $c_n = \left(a_n\right)^{b_n}$ where $a_n \to 1$ and $b_n\to+\infty$ but with different limits for $c_n$; which is why we call $"1^{+\infty}"$ **indeterminate**.

Answer (score 3):

You're clearly misunderstanding what an "indeterminate form" is. The fact that $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form means that knowing $f(n)\to1$ and $g(n)\to \infty$ does not allow us to say anything in *general* about 
$$\lim_n f(n)^{g(n)}$$

However, this does not mean that limits of this kind cannot exist. Examples:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = e $$
and your case
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}1^n = 1. $$

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish from purely a constant base $1$ to a power approaching infinity and *a base that is a function approaching $1$* while its power approaches infinity (and dependent on the same limiting variable).

A constant can never change. A function can. This impacts your end result. Take the famous limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n=e$$

Realize the base *depends on $n$* to approach $1$ while the power also depends on $n$. Thus, the 'different rates of approachment' lead to unexpected results that make it indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{1^n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{1}=1$$
 Since $1^n=1 \ \forall n$, thus the limit is now independent of n and thus stays the same.